# Shouldn’t squaring the (metric) tensor give a scalar?

Tags: metric-spaces, tensor-products, contraction-operator

What I understand is that

$$g^{\mu\nu} g_{\mu\nu} = g^2 = \text{Id}_{4×4}$$

First, is this statement true?

Now if it is, as we are contracting two indices here, shouldn’t the result be a 0-rank tensor not a second-rank tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not look as the square of the metric tensor, but like the product between the metric and its inverse. In general you use upper indices for the inverse.

Anyway, I would write
$$g^{\alpha \mu}g_{\mu \beta} = \delta^{\alpha}_{\beta}.$$
for that product. The result is the identity matrix.

You write 
$g^{\mu \nu}g_{\mu \nu}$, so you are actually taking the trace of the identity matrix: $\delta^{\mu}_{\mu} = n$, where $n$ is the dimension of your space.

Comment: Note $\delta^\mu_\mu = D$, the number of dimensions, implied summation

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one remaining question though: why does the term $\delta^{\mu}_{\mu}$ not signify a contraction over $\mu$ and hence give 4? Like how do I know this is a specific term not a contraction?

Comment: @CDCM I was just asking about this. The metric tensor here is of dimensions 4×4 so shouldn’t $\delta^\mu_\mu$ = 4?

Comment: I edited the answer, that was a good point.